# Confused about path settings with Tornado server

Tags: python-3.x, tornado, bower

I'm using bower to grab the .css and .js files for my website.

The directory structure looks like this:

server.py
bower_components/
templates/

All of the HTML templates (and some partials templates that I use with AngularJS) are located in templates. Stuff installed by bower is located in bower_components. How can I define template_path, static_path and static_url_prefix settings so that I can link into files in those directories?

If I use relative paths like:

href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"

I will get 404 error. No handlers can be found so the error is thrown. It seems that Tornado forces me to use static_url function on my templates? Do I really have to use it? It looks very ugly when mixed with AngularJS. I have tried setting static_path to os.path.dirname(**file**) and tried using static_url but that gives me exception:

Exception: You must define the 'static_path' setting in your application to use static_url

How should I configure this? I can't believe I have wasted hours trying to figure this out already... :(

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to use the [StaticFileHandler](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/web.html?highlight=static#tornado.web.StaticFileHandler)? You can use something like this:

```
import os
import tornado.web
import tornado.ioloop

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))}),
    ])
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Answer (score 1):

You must combine staticfilehandler with some path variables you put in the settings variable.
http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/web.html 
It's pretty easy. You can name as many settings variables as you want.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I needed to use tornado.web.StaticFileHandler class with path mapped to it. This is how I configured my tornado.web.Application:

```
class TornadoApp(tornado.web.Application):

    def __init__(self):
        # static file regex patterns matched with the actual folders here
        static_handlers = {
            '/bower_components/(.*)': 'bower_components',
            '/templates/partials/(.*)': 'templates/partials'
        }
        handlers = [
            ('/', IndexHandler),
            ('/products', ProductHandler),
        ]
        # append the handlers with content from static_handlers dictionary
        for r, p in static_handlers.items():
            handlers.append((r, tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': p}))
        settings = {
            'template_path': "templates",
            'debug': True
        }
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)
```